# How to return ID value from Click event function?

Tags: javascript, events, return

I am a beginner in Javascript. 
I'm trying to get the ID of the clicked button.
I have used a function to get the ID, but I am unable to return the value.
How do I return the ID and use it outside?
the alert statement is for testing.

```js
var getID = function(){

    var ID=this.id;
    alert(ID);

}

document.getElementById('button1').addEventListener('click',getID);
```

```html
<button id="button1">Click Me!</button>
```

Comment: what value do you want to return ?

Comment: the ID of the button

Comment: returning a value from an event handler makes no sense as the return value has no place to go - any code you want to run using the id should be run in the event handler itself

Comment: exactly ! why do you want to access it in some other function ?

Comment: I have added a snippet to your code. It seems to work fine.

Comment: @AbhishekKulkarni - you can access it in any function ... just call that function from the event handler, passing in the ID as an argument ... the issue is you can't *return* a value from an event handler

Comment: i am trying to make a quiz app for practice, after generating random question, i want to get the ID of the option that user has clicked and check the answer using that. So i need to have the ID of the clicked button and the generated question accessible in the same function.

Comment: @JaromandaX thanks that helped me.

Answer (score 1):

```
var getID = function(event){

   var ID = event.target.getAttribute('id');
   alert(ID);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var ID = event.currentTarger.id;
```

The this keyword refers to the current object that the current function is a part of.

At the base level where there appears to be no object, "document" is the actual object. It is an irrelevance to refer to "this" any further in relation to event handler which could be operating within any object and handling events from beyond the object.

Every event triggered has a number of standard attributes attached to it. "currentTarget" is the element upon which the event listener was triggered calling your event handling function.

So long as the event has an id, the element attribute "id" will tell you what that is.

```
var getID = function(event){
   var elementWithID = event.currentTarget;
   var ID = elementWithID.id;
   alert(ID);
}
```

to put it in a more verbose style.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a reference to source clicked element by using `e.target`.

Here is an simple example.

```js
// get all buttons
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button')

// add click event listener to each button
buttons.forEach(button => {
    button.addEventListener('click', e => {
        console.log(`id -> ${e.target.id}`)
    })
})
```

```html
<button id="hello">Hello</button>
<button id="world">World</button>
<button id="i-am">I'm</button>
<button id="happy">Happy</button>
```